# Isn't standard Django login authentication supposed to be case sensitive?

Tags: django, authentication

I am working on a Django web interface.  According to everything that I have read, standard Django authentication, which we are using, is supposed to be case sensitive so that userid, UserId and USERID are three separate user names.

On my Windows 7 machine, both the user registration process and the login authentication are, as expected, case sensitive but when the identical code is ported to our Linux server, both the user registration process and the login authentication become case *insensitive so the userid and USERID are considered the same.

Now, since the registration and authentication processes both change, fears that our team had of registered users being hidden by other registered users have been relieved but I am still concerned that Django on our Linux server functions contrary to documentation.

our global_settings.py contains:

```
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

and settings.py includes:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
'    django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

The only differences that I can see in the two machines are:

```
             case sensitive   case-insensitive
             =========        ======
OS           Windows          Linux
database     SqLite           MySQL
Django ver.  1.4.5            1.4.? / 1.5
```

Can anyone explain the difference in behavior and tell me whether there are any side-effects to watch out for?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Windows vs Linux, or indeed to do with Django at all. This is to do with how you've set up your database: on your server, you are using MySQL, and you have presumably configured it to use a case-insensitive collation (probably latin1_swedish_ci or utf8_general_ci). If you need it to be case-sensitive, use a `bin` collation such as utf8_bin. See the [MySQL charset/collation docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html).

Comment: This explains a lot!  Thank you.